# R: Collapse dataframe of survey with multiple waves/ repeated rows

Tags: r

I have a survey with multiple waves for several respondents, identified in the data by `userid`. There are hundreds of questions, the columns in the `data.table`. The waves and `userid` are the rows of the `data.table`. I'd like to collapse or flatten the waves to one row each for each `userid`. Where a question was used in multiple waves/rows, I'd like to keep the response from the most recent wave. For example, if a question had a response in row 6 and row 7 for a specific `userid`, I want the summary row for that respective `userid` to have the response from row 7. If a column for a respective `userid` ends up having all NA, getting NA in the final output is fine.

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
```

sample data:

```
> dput(testc)
structure(list(userid = c("QW3208", "QW3208", "QW3208", "QW3208", 
"QW3208", "QW3208", "QW3208", "QW3208", "QW3208", "QW3208", "QW3208", 
"QW3208", "QW3227", "QW3227", "QW3227", "QW3227", "QW3227", "QW3227", 
"QW3227", "QW3227", "QW3227", "QW3227", "QW3227", "QW3227"), 
wave_id = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L), .Label = c("Wave 1 ", "Wave 2 ", "Wave 3 ", "Wave 4 ", 
"Wave 5 ", "Wave 6 ", "Wave 7 ", "Wave 8 ", "Wave 9 ", "Wave 10 ", 
"Wave 11 ", "Wave 12 "), class = "factor"), blnc = c(1L, 
2L, NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, 4L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 2L, NA, NA, 
2L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA), lines = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "2", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "2", NA), know = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 1L)), .Names = c("userid", "wave_id", "blnc", "lines", 
"know"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-24L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000350788>)
```

intended output:

```
userid  wave_id blnc lines know
1: QW3208 Wave 12     4     2    1
2: QW3227 Wave 12     1     2    1
```

If I use the following, it works one column at a time:

```
> testc[!is.na(testc$blnc)] %>% group_by(userid) %>% arrange(desc(wave_id)) %>% slice(1)
Source: local data table [2 x 5]
Groups: userid

  userid wave_id  blnc lines  know
   (chr)  (fctr) (int) (int) (int)
1 QW3208 Wave 9      4    NA    NA
2 QW3227 Wave 9      1    NA    NA
```

I can get the results I want for the first column of data here. I don't know how to repeat the sample code across all the columns for each `userid` and have it all come back as a data.table that won't need much clean-up. Most of the columns have values that are integers, but some are factors or characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following splits your data by `userid`, then uses `lapply` to get the most recent not `NA` value in each column. If the column has all `NA`'s, then it returns `NA`.

```
testc %>% 
  split(testc$userid) %>% 
  lapply(function(group_by_id) {
    lapply(group_by_id, function(each_column) {
      each_column <- na.omit(each_column)

      if(length(each_column) == 0) {
        NA
      } else {
        each_column[length(each_column)]
      }

    })
  }) %>% 
  do.call(what = bind_rows, .) %>% 
  data.table()
```

Comment: that worked. Thank you. In my example data I posted here, I changed `userid` to a character variable from a factor and your code wouldn't run with `userid` as factor on a bigger example I made on my computer for testing. Took care of that and it hummed right along. I tried to understand your code and I have to admit, I can't. I thought `lapply()` had to start with a list and the first one you use doesn't seem to. And you create `each_column` from what appears to be thin air to me. I'm not knocking you, you helped me, I'm just trying to understand.

Comment: `lapply` is weird, don't worry. Using `split` with a data.frame (data.table, in this case) in the way we did, creates a list of data.frames grouped by id. We could write `lapply(., a_function)` in the pipe, but I used the abbreviated form.  If you use `lapply` in a list like this, then the function you apply will take each data frame as its argument. That's why we need to nest a `lapply`, so instead we take `each column` of each data.frame as the argument for the function we are applying.